# Is it possible to certify a store application without access to the desktop/from a service?

Tags: windows-8, windows-services, automated-tests, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

So, we're trying to setup an integration test server which will run the certification kit on a Windows Store app. However, we're having problems in that `appcert.exe` just freezes. No errors or anything is logged, it just sits there until our 1 hour timeout is hit.

We're trying to run the certification kit from a Windows Service and with administrative priveldges.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

The app cert kit runs interactively and therefore I suspect it would work properly as a Windows Service. Even if you schedule it to run as a [Windows task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task), it doesn't seem to work.

By default the app certification kit (current version 2.2) is installed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\App Certification Kit\appcertui.exe". If you run it from the command line, it runs as a Windows program with user interface and asks you to select one of the three options: Validate Windows Store App, Validate Desktop App, and Validate Desktop Device App. If you select the first option, the program lists all the apps installed on the testing computer. Once you can select one ore more apps, it actually starts the app(s) you selected, and goes through the testing process.

Comment: There is an `appcert.exe` program which you can run in an automated fashion from the command line. This works for us, just not from a Windows Service